# GitHub Action - Setup secure CockroachDB

Tags: github-actions, workflow, cockroachdb

I would like to automatically start CockroachDB (as a container) with GitHub Actions for automated tests. These tests include testing all ssl modes. That's why I would like to add a user and certificates to CRDB. I searched for environment variables but the there is no documentation for it on the website. At least not for the [container](https://hub.docker.com/r/cockroachdb/cockroach/#!).

Currently I only add it insecurely:

```yaml
  test-backend:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      cockroachdb:
        image: cockroachdb/cockroach
        ports:
          - 26257:26257
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CockroachDB is currently not able to be used as a service in Github Actions which is explained in this issue https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/87043.

As an alternative, here is an example of how it can be run in Github Actions: https://github.com/cockroachdb/sequelize-cockroachdb/blob/188f092dda80a2b11aae1381e83b9581f7bdbfc8/.github/workflows/ci.yml#L37 (instead of `--insecure` pass `--certs-dir`).